# How to assign multiple variables one line that depend on each other in python

Tags: python

So I know that you can assign multiple variables in one line like so:

```py
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

But can you assign a variable based off of the value of another variable in one line?

Idea:

```py
a, b, c = 1, 2, a+b
```

I know that the idea code doesn't work but is there some way to replicate this in one line even if longer or weirder?

NOTE:

Using `;` like below doesn't count

```py
a, b = 1, 2; c = a+b
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TRCK/Desktop/DIP-dev/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    a, b, c = 1, 2, a+b
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: @lainShelvington Cause it gives an error

Comment: @TRCK it doesnt work because they are all being instantiated at the same time, so when c is being instantiated as a+b,  a and b dont exist yet. so this needs to be done on 2 lines

Comment: So it's impossible? I would have thought that it would be possible in some way

Comment: @IainShelvington Can you make that as an answer? I didn't care if it looked good, only if it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the the walrus operator it's possible, if a bit ugly

```
c = (a := 1) + (b := 2)
```

NOTE: Assignment expressions (the walrus operator) are only available from Python 3.8 onwards

Comment: I never knew something like this existed in python. Thanks for answering

Comment: Also works to reference previous expressions, e.g. `c = (a := 1) + (b := 2 + a)`

Comment: That's incredible

Comment: Wait it doesn't work on `python3.6.9` . I am getting the following error.  `File "<stdin>", line 1
    c = (a:= 1) + (b:= 2)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: That's cause the walrus operator is 3.8+

Comment: This doesn't work: `(minimum_width := self.winfo_reqwidth()), (minimum_height := self.winfo_reqheight()), (x_coords := int(self.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - minimum_width/2)) (y_coords := int(self.winfo_screenheight()/2 - minimum_height/2)-20)`

Comment: @TRCK Looks like you're just missing a comma here `...minimum_width/2)), (y_coords :=...`

Comment: @IainShelvington One last question, when I try to make a self variable with the walrus operator it throws the error: `SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with attribute`. The code to replicate is `(self.example := 5)`